# How to count displayed rows in Richfaces DataTable with custom filtering?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 4.1.0 final, and I want to count the rows displayed after filtering. I am using custom filter functions:

```
public Filter<?> getSessionNameFilterImpl() {
    Filter<Object> temp = new Filter<Object>() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Object item) {
            if (sessionNameFilter(item)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                filtered--; //counter for recording how many rows were denied
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    return temp;
}

private boolean sessionNameFilter(Object item) {
    //filter implementation here
}
```

I tried with a counter (named 'filtered') but its value is unchanged.

Comment: If you have data model for datatable, then you can retrieve row count from model using `dm.getRowCount();`. In that moment filtering is internal operation inside data model and you don't need any additional function. With your custom filter rowCount = fullRowAmount - filtered.

Comment: Currently I am not using DataModels, but I seem promising. Could you post an answer with links to examples?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Filter<?> getSessionNameFilterImpl() {
Filter<Object> temp = new Filter<Object>() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Object item) {
        if (sessionNameFilter(item)) {
           all.add(item);
            return true;
        } else {
          all.remove(item);
            return false;
        }
    }
};
return temp;
```

}

```
public Integer getTotalShow(){
    return all.size();
}
```

private Set all = new HashSet();

> Note: must call all.clear(); when you update data Table source.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `list` is your list of objects

Reset the counter at the beginning of the filter, increase the counter everytime a object is filtered (`return false`), and then display the size of the list minus the `filtered` counter:

```
...

List<Object> list;
int filtered;

...

public Filter<?> getSessionNameFilterImpl() {
    filtered = 0;

    Filter<Object> temp = new Filter<Object>() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Object item) {
            if (sessionNameFilter(item)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                filtered++; //counter for recording how many rows were denied
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    return temp;
}

public int getRowCount(){
    return list.size()-filtered;
}
```